# Connection of 3 parallel conducting plates

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

I have a scenario where 3 parallel conducting plates are interconnected with a wire joining all 3. Each plate has a charge $Q$ and the set-up is allowed to attain electrostatic condition. Now my question is, in the end, what'll be the charge distribution of these plates? The distance between the 1st 2 plates is $a$ and between the 2nd and 3rd plates is $b$. Now obviously, the outer surfaces will have a charge of $\frac{3Q}{2}$, but I'm unable to understand how to balance their potentials to figure out the charge distributions on the other faces of the plates. I have figured out a solution as to what'd happen when only the plates in the extremes would be connected but am unable to visualise or compute what'd happen when all 3 are interconnected.

Comment: When all three are connected, they are on the same potential so the have the same amount of charge namely Q , there is no reason why the initial charges should move. I don't see your "obviously"

Comment: *the outer surfaces will have a charge of 3Q/2*, which means that all the charge is accounted for.  Having additional charges (positive and negative ) in addition to the charges on the outside would represent a higher energy state.

Comment: @trula It can't stay the same in order to make field inside the conductor 0

Comment: @Farcher okay that makes sense! Thanks